# I have a table similar to the following .i want the individual count of the different status available

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Data

```
id |name     | status         |location 
----------------------------------
 1 |ABCD     |completed       | Delhi
 2 |QWER     |construction    | Mumbai
 3 |RBVF     |To_launch       | Chennai
 4 |POIU     |ready           | Kolkata
 5 |WABCD    |completed       | Delhi
 6 |RQWER    |construction    | Mumbai
 7 |TRBVF    |To_launch       | Chennai
 8 |UPOIU     |ready           | Kolkata
 9 |RBVF      |To_launch       | Chennai
 10|POIU      |ready           | Kolkata
 11|WABCD     |completed       | Delhi
```

lets say my output should be like

```
construction status      count
completed                  4
To_launch                  3
ready                      3
construction               2
```

I have tried something like

```
select d.status, count(d.status)
from data d
where d.status = 'completed'
```

but i want all status results to come in a single Query.But iam unable to figure it out.TIA..Please do suggest to improve myself in SQL.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi Thanks what if i have to give
construction status      count
completed                  4
To_launch                  3
ready                      3
construction               2
sum                         12

sum of all counts in same Query

Comment: Did you try the GROUP BY? Did you look up the GROUP BY syntax?

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `count`  and `group by` clause

```
   select status as `construction status` ,count（*）as Cnt from Yourtable
    group by status
```

below query also shows total as wanted in your comment

```
   select status as `construction status`, count(*) as count, total from  
   Yourtable,(select count(*) as total from Yourtable) t2 
   group by status
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8abcce/4

Comment: Hi Thanks what if i have to give 
construction status count
 completed 4 
To_launch 3 
ready 3 
construction 2 
sum 12 
sum of all counts in same Query

Comment: @Geek123 can you share your output sample as like that gave in your question

Comment: @Geek123 if it helps you as a appreciation of Stackoverflow you will upvote ,accept answer

Comment: @Geek123 look another version query that will shows total